# $f''(x)-g''(x)=0$, $f'(A)=2$, $g'(A)=4$, $f(B)=3$, $g(B)=9$, then $f(\frac{3}{2})-g(\frac{3}{2})$ is

Tags: calculus

$f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are two differentiable function in $[0,2]$ such that $f''(x)-g''(x)=0$, $f'(A)=2$, $g'(A)=4$, $f(B)=3$, $g(B)=9$. Then $f(\frac{3}{2})-g(\frac{3}{2})$ is

(a) $0$
(b) $2$
(c) $10$
(d) $-5$

---

$f''(x)=g''(x)\implies f'(x)=g'(x)+c\implies f'(A)=g'(B)+c\implies c=-2$

$f'(x)=g'(x)-2\implies f(x)=g(x)-2x+d\implies f(B)=g(B)-2B+d$
$3=9-2B+d$

I am stuck here

Comment: Define $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$ and then forget about $f$ and $g$.

Comment: I tried but could not get answer.

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: Is the answer $-5?$

Comment: yes the answer is $-5$

Comment: Oh really..I  took $x=0$ in first equation ...then $A=1$ and $B=2$....Great coincidence

Comment: I know this may be a silly question, but can we assume that A and B are on the interval? Sorry to ask, but it's not stated explicitly.

Comment: yes A and B are in the interval,i suppose.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that A and B are on the interval....

From what you had, $f(x)-g(x)=-2x+2(B-3)$. Inputting $x=3/2$ there gives $f(\frac{3}{2})-g(\frac{3}{2})=-9+2B$. Plug in each possible answer. It's only -5 that gives B on the interval (i.e. $f(\frac{3}{2})-g(\frac{3}{2})=-5$ implies $B=2$). The other choices leave B off the interval.